# How to force an android application to send network requests over cellular data even when connected to wifi?

Tags: java, android, react-native, mobile, okhttp

I have an android application in java where frequently the phone will be connected to a wifi-network that is not connected to the internet. When I try to make network requests, such as to api endpoints, it tries to send the requests over this wifi network, which then fail because it is not connected to the internet. When this happens, I would like some sort of a fallback where the requests are instead routed over the device's cellular data. Currently I am using okhttp3 to make these network requests, but I am open to other solutions

This is how I am currently attempting to alleviate the issue (where variable transport is equal to NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR:

```
  private void connectToNetworkWithSpecifiedCapability(OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder, int transport) {
    Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();

    for (Network network : networks) {
      NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
      NetworkCapabilities caps = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);

      if(caps == null || netInfo == null){
        continue;
      }

      if(!netInfo.isConnected()){
        continue;
      }

      if(caps.hasTransport(transport)){
        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
        clientBuilder.proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
        clientBuilder.socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory());
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```